# SharePoint Online - Redirect to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I am using SharePoint Online and have inserted a `Script editor webpart` with the following code to redirect from page - "SPage" to page "Pages". However it is not working, can anyone provide me assistance in getting this to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href === 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/SPage.aspx'){
    location.replace ("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/Pages.aspx");
    return False;
}
</script>
```

Comment: For future reference, "it is not working" is not very helpful.  Please explain how it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
if(location.href === 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/SPage.aspx')
{
     location.href = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/Pages.aspx";
}
```

Comment: if we have multiple site collections under the same web collection, is it best practice to write this javascript in the site collection master page?

Comment: @hkhan yes, that would be the way to go if you want it across multiple site collections in a web app.

Answer (score 3):

first convert the LHS and RHS to lowercase and compare.

```
var spageUrl = 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/SPage.aspx';
if(location.href.toLowerCase() === spageUrl.toLowerCase())
{
     location.href = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/SitePages/Pages.aspx";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer Amit. I havent been able to check if it works or not as I used the solution provided by Gautam first and it was successfull for me

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
url = url.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/';
var check_URL = url + "SitePages/SPage.aspx";
var redirectURL = url + "SitePages/Pages.aspx";
if(location.href === check_URL)
{
    window.location = redirectURL;
}
```